# what's the right way to use sublime in multiple X11 sessions?

Tags: sublimetext, x11

On my redhat 6 machine:

- I opened 2 sublime windows on one of my X11 session, with display :0.
- Went to a new X11 session with display :5.
- I issued sublime (also tried "sublime -n"), nothing happened.
- I ran "ps -ef |grep sublime", then killed all sublime processes.
- Now, I issued sublime again, I got new sublime window on my display (:5), also additional 2 sublime windows as I had in display :0.

My question: any better way to have multiple sublime windows in my difference X11 sessions? I would like to still keep my old sublime windows in :0, and have new sublime windows in my :5.

Comment: Did you repeat this more than once to ensure this is actually what's going on? You *should* be able to run Sublime windows on multiple displays, all connecting to the same process of `sublime_text` and `plugin_host`. AFAIK a single user can't run multiple Sublime instances, but multiple windows should be no problem. Sorry I can't test it personally, I'm on Ubuntu with Gnome/Unity that uses separate workspaces, but not X11 displays. That I know of...

Comment: Sorry for the late update, I tried again, this time I can't reproduce. What I did was to run sublime on 2 X11 session, each of which has its own display. but I did observed that I have 2 sublime instance running in this case: [$ ps -ef |grep sublime;
/home/mzhao/sublime_text_3/plugin_host 4398;
/home/mzhao/sublime_text_3/plugin_host 4421]
I think it's a big mess. I will just try not to use sublime on multiple X11 sessions at the same time.